# how to convert or transform a norm square equation to a concave form?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming, cvx, non-convex

so the objective function is similar to |h x theta x g|^2,where h is a nx1 complex row vector, theta is n x n complex matrix, g is a n x 1 column vector.

If I want to maximize this, in cvx, maximize a convex function is not allowed.

how can I transform it to an concave equivalent form?

Comment: That is in general not possible. Sometimes the first-order conditions (or KKT conditions if there are constraints) lead to easier to solve problems.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I actually used a first order approximation to solve it.